# Subclass Button with Android : lots of errors

Tags: android, subclass

I tried to subclass `Button` , but I have a lot of errors when launching my project. Could you have a look and tell me how to fix this? (I've got maybe 50 errors coming up)

```
package my.project.name;

import android[...]

public class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton(){
        super(null);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvasObject) {
        super.onDraw(canvasObject);
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        int width = 80;
        int height = 200;
        Paint thePaint = new Paint();   
        thePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        RectF rectangle1 = new RectF(x,y,x+width,y+height);
        canvasObject.drawRoundRect(rectangle1, 10.0f, 10.0f, thePaint);   
    }

}
```

the main class :

```
package my.project.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyProjectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

and the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <MyButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myb"
        android:tag="tag"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: actually, the rectangle does not show up, the subclass works, because i've got no error, but the rectangle is just not visible, even with the background to "@null"...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Um, what errors? That's kind of an important detail. One thing I see offhand, you have to use the fully qualified name of your button in the XML. (e.g. `my.project.name.MyButton`)

Comment: please add some of the errors you recieve. Also you have to Write the fully qualified namespace in your xml. Like <your.package.from.button.MyButton .... />

Comment: @Rafael T : thanks a lot guys! it works fine, could someone put the answer as a "message" so that i can check it as the answer? Thanks again!

Comment: @kcoppock : thanks a lot guys! it works fine, could someone put the answer as a "message" so that i can check it as the answer? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rename

```
<MyButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myb"
    android:tag="tag"
     />
```

to a fully qualified Namespace

```
<namespace.from.button.MyButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myb"
    android:tag="tag"
     />
```

Comment: thanks Rafael, about the constructors, do all the constructors have to be re-written in the subclass? or this may cause an error somehow?

Comment: needed Constructors are depending on your use of the Button: MyButton(Context) is usually invoked inside Java. You are inflating the Button from XML so you need Button(Context, AttributeSet) only.

Comment: thanks, sorry again, i don't want to ask too much, but i edited my post : the subclass does not contain any error at launching, but the "rectangle" is not shown on screen... do you know why?

Comment: i don't know, but you can put Logs like with `Log.d("MyButton", "onDraw triggered")`to see if the methods gets triggered. If not look inside draw(Canvas). Also I'm not shure if you need to call super.onDraw as you want a custom style.

Comment: thanks, do you see anything else? the log doesn't work, i placed it in my onCreate method or in MyButton class, but i don't see it in the console. If i comment the line super.onDraw, the text (set in the xml file) is not visible anymore. Any idea maybe?

Comment: you dont see log messages in the console, but in Eclipse there is a "LogCat" Tab to press.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fully-qualified name for the element in the XML layout does not work if your Button subclass is an inner class. If this is the case, you need to add a class attribute and use the generic **view** for the element name.

```
<view
    class="my.project.name.MyProjectActivity$MyButton"
    ...
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html