# Change background of all buttons

Tags: android, android-button

I would like to change the background of all the `Buttons` in a `View`.

```
android:background="@drawable/button_red"
```

And i would like to do this in an `OnClick()` event.

```
android:onClick="ChangeCouleur"
```

I would like to do this in a `foreach` loop, but i am not sure how to do this.

For example:

```
for( b in ... )
    if (b.getid()!=idofthebutton)
         b.setbackgroud(button_red)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you want to change bg of all buttons or only one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all your `Buttons` in an `Array` of `Buttons`, then cycle to it an change the background.

```
Button button1 = (Button)this.findViewById(...);
Button button2 = (Button)this.findViewById(...);
Button button3 = (Button)this.findViewById(...);

Button[] buttons={button1, button2, button3};

for (Button currentButton : buttons) {
    currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_new_background);
}
```

Comment: This will accomplish what you are wanting. And if you wanted it dynamic, just have an `ArrayList` of `Buttons` and do the same thing.

Comment: here button1, button2 are the id of my button ?

Comment: No, they are the `Button` objects. Added clarity to the answer.

Comment: They are the objects, like: Button button1=(Button)findViewById(...);

Comment: Button[] buttons={button1, button2}; i have an error on this line "Multiple markers at this line"

Comment: This line is OK. Make sure you are getting the button references properly. Also, do a clean: Project -> Clean, and re-format the code: CTRL+SHIFT+F.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the background of the clicked button

```
public void changeColor(View v) {
    v.setBackground(btn_red);
}
```

Comment: You can use the `changeColor(...)` method mentioned above, but you would need to pass each `Button` in to this method as an argument. So, i am not sure this solves your problem. I am assuming your main concern is getting all the `Buttons` in your `View`, am i correct?

Comment: As the question was not clear, it seemed like he wanted to change the bg of clicked button.. but wt he wants is opposite.. change bg of all butns except clicked one

Comment: Agreed, question was not clear. I fixed it for him, should be clear now.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is subclass `Button`, then make all the buttons in you app instances of your new class. That way, if you decide that you want to adjust the color or change something else, you only have to do it once, and it will change all the buttons in your app. [Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436077/subclass-button-with-android-lots-of-errors) that should give you some pointers on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get a reference to all the Buttons. Add them to an ArrayList or something similar. In your ChangeCouleur method use a loop to iterate through all the buttons changing the color of each one.

Answer (score 1):

Create .XML file in your “res/drawable/” and use selector attribute in it.And use different images for the button.Please refer this link.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

This will clear your idea. :)